# Divs inside div how to make borders and how to make div next to div

Tags: html, position, height, width

How to make something like this?

[image]

One big parent div with no space between screen border top and left? That first div should move and that
with title shouldn't. I have no idea how to do it. Please for answers with inline added CSS (e.g ) [http://jsfiddle.net/yqLsk79z/](https://jsfiddle.net/yqLsk79z/)

```
<!doctype html>
<html >
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  </head>
  <body bgcolor="grey">
    <div style="position:fixed;height:100%;  width:10%; text-align:center; border: solid
      <div style="height: 10%"> <a href="cos.html"> Cos </a> </div>
      <div style="height: 10%"> <a href="sic.html"> Sic </a> </div>
      <div style="height: 10%"> <a href="sic.html"> Sic </a> </div> 
      <div style="height: 10%"> <a href="sic.html"> Sic </a> </div> 
      <div style="height: 10%"> <a href="sic.html"> Sic </a> </div> 
      <div style="height: 10%"> <a href="sic.html"> Sic </a> </div> 
      <div style="height: 10%"> <a href="sic.html"> Sic </a> </div> 
      <div style="height: 10%"> <a href="sic.html"> Sic </a> </div> 
      <div style="height: 10%"> <a href="sic.html"> Sic </a> </div> 
      <div style="height: 10%"> <a href="sic.html"> Sic </a> </div> 
    </div>
    <div style="height:10%; width: 90%"> Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add margin:0 to you body tag to remove the space around the edge.

Change the body tag to this;

```
<body bgcolor="grey" style="margin:0;">
```

You also need to apply a style pushing the header and content divs 10% from the left. See the fiddle for example of this.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qyvL55uc/3/)

If that is not what you are after leave a comment below explaining what 'the first div should move' means, and I'll have another look.

Can I ask why you specifically need inline styles? A slightly better way would be to use a reset in css. Within your head add;

```
<style>
    *{margin:0;}
</style>
```